# Anyone knows the Phillips Picopix projector vga cable

Tags: vga, cable, projector

Hello there superusers.
I am on a quest to find a very specific cable ( or an alternative to it). It is a vga+ 3.5mm audio to mini hdmi, reference PPA1150, that are used to connect a computer to a picopix 1230 pico projector i had laying around. I am trying to use it in an off-grid shed by the sea( so it won't be too hard on the solar batteries during the night movie session.
But ( and it's a big but) i can't find it anywhere in stock, not even some kind of schematics to DIY one. From the vendor pictures it seems like a  passive adapter, and i've tried making one but i couldn't find out a working cable combination.
Thanks for reading my long cry for help.
[image]

Comment: It's certainly not passive - HDMI is 100% digital and VGA and 3.5 mm audio are 100% analog. There must be something to do the conversion.

Comment: That's the thing the projector has a mini hdmi port but the signal is analog. They apparently chose the mini hdmi because it is smaller than a bulky vga. I can confirm this because i have tried using a hdmi to micro adapter, switching resolutions still no signal.

Comment: If it's a custom thing then unfortunately you're probably out of luck - I doubt replacements are available anywhere